# Uncaught type error: mychart.update is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am building external buttons to toggle the visibility of data from chartjs, but it will only works when the screen size changed. So, I found that can use mychart.update() to solve the problem. But it get me the error that I stated in the title.

Here is my chart:

```
var myRadarChart = {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
            labels: lbl,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Houses',
                    data: yh,
                    backgroundColor:['rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5)'],
                    borderColor: ['rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.8)'],
                    hidden:false
                },
                {
                    label: 'Apartments',
                    data: ya,
                    backgroundColor:['rgba(40,167,69, 0.5)'],
                    borderColor: ['rgba(40,167,69, 0.8)'],
                    hidden:false
                },
                {
                    label: 'Rooms',
                    data: yr,
                    backgroundColor:['rgba(218, 17, 61,0.5)'],
                    borderColor: ['rgba(218,17,61,0.8)'],
                    hidden:false
                }
            ]

        },
    options: {
        legend:{
            display:true,
            onHover: function(event, legendItem) {
            document.getElementById("myRadarChart").style.cursor = 'pointer';},
        },
        maintainAspectRatio:false,
        scale: {
            angleLines: {
                display: true
                },
            ticks: {
                suggestedMin: 0,
                suggestedMax: 0
                }
            }
        }
    };
var ctx = document.getElementById('myRadarChart').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, myRadarChart);
```

And how I trying to do is:

```
//Onclick
function getData(dontHide){
switch(dontHide){
        case 0:
            myRadarChart.data.datasets[0].hidden=false;
            myRadarChart.data.datasets[1].hidden=true;
            myRadarChart.data.datasets[2].hidden=true;
            myRadarChart.update();
            break;
        case 1:
            myRadarChart.data.datasets[0].hidden=true;
            myRadarChart.data.datasets[1].hidden=false;
            myRadarChart.data.datasets[2].hidden=true;
            myRadarChart.update();
            break;
        case 2:
            myRadarChart.data.datasets[0].hidden=true;
            myRadarChart.data.datasets[1].hidden=true;
            myRadarChart.data.datasets[2].hidden=false;
            myRadarChart.update();
            break;
    }
}
```

Or is there alternative ways to perform something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you're trying to call the `.update()` method on your graph's *config* object, not your actual graph instance. As you can see, `myRadarChart` is just an object, it doesn't have a method called `update()` on it. However, the graph you create when doing `new Chart(ctx, myRadarChart);` does give you the `.update()` method.

To fix your issue, you'll need to first store the instance of your graph somewhere:

```
var radarGraph = new Chart(ctx, myRadarChart);
```

Then update the graph's data (rather than your config object directly):

```
radarGraph.data.datasets[0].hidden = false;
...
```

Then call the update method on your `radarGraph` object:

```
radarGraph.update();
```