# Chart.update is not a function typeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I get this error when trying to click some buttons on my web app.

> "TypeError: chart.update is not a function"

I'm trying to make user interactive charts using react and chart.js. I found [this documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html) for chart.js and have implemented the `addData()` and `removeData()` functions, but I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Any advice would be appreciated! I'm a total beginner to javascript and react. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

class Orders extends Component {
  state = {};
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addData = this.addData.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      chartData: {
        labels: ["Shoes", "Necklace", "T-Shirt", "Jeans", "Sweater", "Hat"],
        datasets: [
          {
            fill: "start",
            label: "Number of Orders Today",
            data: [32, 45, 12, 76, 70, 19],
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)",
              "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)",
              "rgba(201, 99, 132, 0.6)",
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  }

  addData(chart) {
    console.log(document.getElementById("category").value);
    chart.labels.push(document.getElementById("category").value);
    console.log(chart.labels);
    chart.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
      dataset.data.push(document.getElementById("numOfOrders").value * 1);
    });
    chart.update();
  }

  removeData(chart) {
    chart.labels.pop();
    chart.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
      dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="orders">
        <h1>Orders</h1>
        <div style={{ height: "500px", width: "500px" }}>
          <Bar
            data={this.state.chartData}
            options={{
              responsive: true,
              title: { text: "" },
            }}
          />
          <div>
            <label for="numOfOrders">NumberOfOrders:</label>
            <input name="numOfOrders" id="numOfOrders" type="number"></input>
            <label for="item">Item:</label>
            <input name="item" id="category" type="text"></input>
          </div>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              this.addData(this.state.chartData);
            }}
          >
            Add Item
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              this.removeData(this.state.chartData);
            }}
          >
            Remove Item
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Orders;
```

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61283199/uncaught-type-error-mychart-update-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you invoke `update()` on the `chartData` object but not on the chart instance. The `chartData` object does not have an `update()` function.

How to get a reference to the Chart.js instance is explained [here](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2#chartjs-instance).

Below code fragments illustrate what needs to be changed in your code to solve your problem.

```
constructor() {
  ... 
  this.chartReference = React.createRef(); 
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.chart = this.chartReference.current.chartInstance;
  ...
}

addData(chart) {
   ...
   this.chart.update(); // instead of chart.update();
}

removeData(chart) {
   ...
   this.chart.update(); // instead of chart.update();
}

render() {
  return (
    ...
    <Bar
      ref={this.chartReference}
      ...
    />
    ...
  );
}
```